# jQuery ajax call: how to pass object without .serialize() or.param()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

I have a javascript hash (object?) we will call `settings_hash` that basically looks like this:

```
{ setting_1=90, setting_2=30, setting_3=19 }
```

And I've got a post that looks like this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("model/queries.cfc", {
    method: 'methodName',
    data: jQuery.param(settings_hash),
    }, function(data){
        // callback stuff goes here
    }
);
```

I really don't like having to decode the data string on my queries page (it's coldfusion- bleah). Is there an easy way to handle the decode a little better on the client side? So that what we *functionally* get is this:

```
jQuery.getJSON("model/queries.cfc", {
    method: 'methodName',
    setting1: 90,
    setting2: 30,
    setting2: 19,
    }, function(data){
        // callback stuff goes here
    }
);
```

Obviously if .serialize() or .param() is the way to go, then that's fine. What I want to avoid is a big long string that I have to decode, like `data=setting_1%3D90%26setting2%3D30%26setting3%3D19`. Open to all solutions/feedback- if the big long string is really the way to go for some reason, convince me and you'll get credit for the answer!

Comment: your object should be use ":" not "=" and you should be able to just pass the object as it stands rather than using param() or serialize().

Comment: Note Param() is used internally by Jquery so you don't need to do it manually

Comment: Changing the "=" to ":" give me an error. Here's how that hash is being built: `settings_hash = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    item = data[i];
    settings_hash[item[0]] = item[1];
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "hash" isn't a valid JavaScript object literal that can be serialized into JSON.

Convert from what you have to simply using an actualy JS object literal, like this:

```
var data = {
    method: 'methodName',
    setting1: 90,
    setting2: 30,
    setting2: 19
}
```

Then just pass to your AJAX call, no manual serialization necessary:

```
jQuery.post(url, data, callback);

function callback(d) {
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: This is how the hash is built: `settings_hash = {}; for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { item = data[i]; settings_hash[item[0]] = item[1]; }`. How would I change it?

Comment: What you're constructing there is a valid JS object and you wouldn't need to change it any.  If you wanted to add additional properties to it, like "method", you can just later do `settings_hash.method = "blah";`  Also note that your object, despite using the `=` assignment, is expressed in the exact way I did above: `{ property: value }`.  This is JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) when expressed entirely as a string, or a JavaScript Object Literal when expressed as... well, an object literal (not a string)!